# Error with `Sys.setenv("VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE")` in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm working on R shiny and I get an error:

> The size of the connection buffer (131072) was not large enough
> to fit a complete line:
>
> - Increase it by setting `Sys.setenv("VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE")`

so I ran

```
Sys.setenv(VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE=500072)
```

in my console and the error is solved in my result panel. However when I publish it on the web, I get the error.

I'm assuming that it is because when I run `Sys.setenv(VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE=500072)`, it only applies to my local working space and it does not apply to my shiny web.

If I include `Sys.setenv(VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE=500072)` in my app.r file, it still gives me an error.

Is there a specific place where I run `Sys.setenv(VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE=500072)` for Shiny?

I tried putting it in the inside

```
server <- function(input, output){}
```

and also the outside, but both doesn't work.

Comment: You could include a `.Renviron` file in the root of the Shiny app on the web, and set environment variables in that file: just include the line `VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE=500072`.

Comment: @neilfws So do you mean I need to make a separate .R script file named ".Renviron" and save it to the file where my app.R is? Then I also need to source the file in the app.R right? For example: source(".Renviron")

Comment: Yes, but I don't think you need to source the `.Renviron` file. At least when I tried on my system, simply having the file in the same directory was sufficient, but that was for a local app. Give it a go and let me know!

Comment: @neilfws Thank you so much for the help. I created a r script file named ".Renviron.R" and saved it inside the shiny folder where my app.R is. However, if I don't source  the file I still get an error: The size of the connection buffer (131072) was not large enough
to fit a complete line:
  * Increase it by setting `Sys.setenv("VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE")` . When I sourced the file it works well on my result panel but doesn't show up on the published web.

Comment: The file isn't an R script, don't suffix it with `.R`. It's an environment file and needs to be named simply `.Renviron`.

Comment: @neilfws I'm sorry if this is really a basic question but how do you create a .Renviron file? I tried to search in google and I tried creating a new text file (File > New File > Text File) and save it as .Renviron from http://www.dartistics.com/googleanalytics/setup.html#:~:text=Renviron%20file%20in%20your%20Home,Renviron%20. But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Just use any text editor. It looks like you created the file but didn't add the line defining the variable?

Comment: @neilfws So I created a textfile named .Renviron in the same location wherer my app.R is and included VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE=500072 in the .Renviron file. It's not working even on my result panel, meaning it's not applied to my local workspace as well? Also when I tried publishng it even though I try to name it .Renviron without suffix, it has created as .Renviron.rtf. Is this ok?

Comment: The rtf suffix is a problem. Sounds like you are on Windows...and perhaps file explorer doesn't show the suffix by default even though it is there. You need to get rid of it. All I can say is: when I made a .Renviron file containing "MYVAR=abcdef" and a simple example Shiny app which simply displayed the value of MYVAR - it worked for me, also on Windows.

Comment: @neilfws  I think it now works like what you said, but it's still not displaying when it is deployed. I think maybe it's wrong somewhere else. But anyways thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm assuming the `.Renviron` file was deployed too? Last suggestion: try `readRenviron(".Renviron")` near the top of the `app.R` file.